# Android. Firebase crashlytics interpretation

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I use Firebase / Crashlytics in my Android App.

I have a crash scenario that is caught and reported in Firebase.
I'm unsure about how to interpret the crash report.

In Firebase it says:

Fatal Exception: b.c.a.a
Application Not Responding for at least 5000 ms.

```
Caused by b.c.a.a$a$a
main (state = RUNNABLE)
net.q_play.player.MainActivity$1.run

android.util.Log.println_native (Log.java)
android.util.Log.d (Log.java:143)
net.q_play.player.MainActivity$1.run (MainActivity.java:24)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:755)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6141)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:912)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

a) I think it is ANR (application-not-responding related)

b) What does "Caused by b.c.a.a$a$a" mean?

c) The pinpointed line: net.q_play.player.MainActivity$1.run (MainActivity.java:24)
It doesn't make sense in line 24 - as this is: import android.database.Cursor;

Hope for some inputs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabric/Firebaser here, I can give some input for b) -

b) Looks like the crashing method has had its method name obfuscated. If you're using something like Proguard to obfuscate your app, make sure you've followed all the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports-new-sdk?platform=android) to get deobfuscated Crashlytics crash reports.

Otherwise, I'm no expert on Android errors or resource usage, but this looks ANR-related to me as well. Hope you can get some more insight into this particular crash.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get the full stack trace from a running instance. It confirmed that in fact it did experience and ANR caused by some GPU rendering issues on webview.